# Removing a many to Many relationship using soft delete Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to deleting query in table user_post(user_id, post_id);

I have this join

```
     /**
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_post",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $posts;
```

zone and post do not need to be deleted
How can i do this?

i have no idea how to do it